# How to assign values to the correct array index?

Tags: arrays, bash

Is it possible when I want to assign values to the correct index in array (array in bash)? when I enter some number I want that this number was on the same position as its value..

example: when I enter number **25** and then use command `echo ${array[25]}` I expect **25**

I want to give numbers from `shuf -i 1-49 -n 7 | xargs -n7` to array. Every number on his position.

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: You want to create a sparse array of seven random values each assigned to its index value?

Comment: Can you explain why you'd want this? If I enter 25, why pull up `${a[25]}` just to get the value of `25`? It's certainly not very efficient. Imagine if I `define array foo`, then said `foo[1000]='bar'`. I'd be taking up 1001 memory locations. There might be a better way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could just loop over the result of `shuf`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read i
do
  a[$i]=$i
done < <( shuf -i 1-49 -n 7 )

for i in "${!a[@]}"; do
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${a[$i]}"
done
```